# Summing integers recursive with Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to calculate a sum of two integers by using a recursive algorithm, but sincerely i have no idea how to do so. Here are the conditions:

sum(x,y) = ? 
**if** x = 0 **then** sum (x,y) = y **otherwise** sum(x,y) = sum(predecessor(x),successor(y)).

Does someone have an idea how i could write this in an algorithm? I would be glad about any advice.

Comment: you have the algorithm right there

Comment: Why did you answer your question while you were asking it?

Comment: note: this only works if x is not negative.

Comment: MAX_INT should be an issue too then

Comment: Does this have any advantages? How about `x + y`?

Comment: @Martijn, Not really, more like an exercise to practice recursion.

Comment: @Muggen MAX_INT is actually less an issue, as in case `x` is negative it'll reach zero anyway (not sure the stack will cope happily with the possibly 2^31 recursions though :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I won't give you the code since this seems to be a homework but here is the rough algorithm:

```
predecessor(x) = x - 1
successor(x) = x + 1

sum(x, y) = 
  if x = 0 
    then y 
    otherwise sum(predecessor(x), successor(y))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really don't need the code. I'm just not sure how to write this algorithm. Are you sure that the definition of predessor and successor is correct?

Comment: @Ordo: write the code and find out! or just run this pseudocode in your head (or on paper).

Comment: Not sure if naming the parameter to be `x` for predecessor() and successor() is a good idea, for a beginner...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for i&j both >= 0. set sum = 0; and subtract 1 until it is <= 0

```
 public static int sum(int i, int j){
           return sum(i,j,0);
 }

 private static int sum(int i, int j, int sum) {
    if (i <= 0 && j <= 0) {
        return sum;
    } else if (i <= 0) {
        return sum(0, j - 1, sum + 1);
    } else if (j <= 0) {
        return sum(i - 1, 0, sum + 1);
    } else {
        return sum(i - 1, j - 1, sum + 2);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(60, 7)); 

    }
```

Comment: @Martijn "the best way it is the well known way to you" :) . it comes first to my mind and something different

Comment: This is complicated. The algorithm given by OP is simpler. Also, it leaves room for error by depending on user to supply `sum` as 0.

Comment: In the *conditions* the interface requires that the two functions successor(x) and predecessor(x) are implemented. Probably for a reason :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's the simplest I could immagine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("4+5 = " + sum(4, 5));
    System.out.println("4+(-5) = " + sum(4, -5));
    System.out.println("-4+5 = " + sum(-4, 5));
    System.out.println("-4+5 = " + sum(-4, -5));
}

public static int sum(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0) {
        x *= -1;
        y *= -1;
    }
    return (x == 0 ? y : sum(--x, ++y));
}
```

Comment: @ring0: That's the same, just that it won't work with negatives and it is not java

Answer (score 1):

Javaish pseudo code corresponding to your code in your question

```
sum(x, y): return x == 0 ? y : sum(x-1, y+1)
```

Works for any pair of numbers where *x* is a non-negative integer.

Comment: @ring0, for the algoritm given; a negative x would recurse using a decremented x which will never become 0 resulting in overflow if it doen't run out of stack first.

Comment: Not really, when `x` reaches `-2147483648` or `-2^31` the next call with `x-1` sets `2147483647` for x, being now positive. Since `0x80000000-1` is `0x7fffffff`. The stack will probably suffer a bit anyway :-) But it's a Java stack... so it may be ok!

Comment: @ring0, positive integer was a typo. should have been non-negative. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

To handle negative numbers based on @aioobe's answer.

```
sum(x, y): return x == 0 ? y : x < 0 ? ~sum(~x, -y) : sum(x-1, y+1)
```

Note: the rather optimisic use of ~ to avoid blowing up on x=MIN_VALUE. ;)